Is a big open-loop phase margin of an op-amp always better for system stability?
Because of the obsolete op-amp LM6171B, Texas Instruments recommends the LM6171A as a replacement part. In general the A grade has better specs like bandwidth, CMR etc. I noticed that the open-loop phase margins specified in the datasheet differ a lot though. While B Grade has only 40° at phase margin (+/- 15 V supply), the A Grade op-amp has 58°. In general I would say that a bigger phase margin would be better in most cases, but are there any scenarios or configurations where a bigger open-loop phase margin could make a closed-loop system more unstable?

It depends on your feedback network and gain margin. If you account for your whole loop (op amp, RC's, and plant dynamics), sure, higher phase margin amounts to a more stable system.

A larger phase margin will give you more loop stability. That is good if stability is what you are after - absence of ringing, tolerance to large changes in dynamics of the components.
Sometimes, people want settling time very close to the final value - think an ADC buffer where you want to settle to 1/2LSB of a 12 bit ADC as quickly as possible after a step. In this application, you can have 'too much' stability. You want to aim at a critically damped system, not an over-damped system that would have a long settling tail. But it's a lot easier to dial back too much stability, than it is to get it when it's lacking.
